# LTspice- Comparing Load current of capacitance multiplier and RC filter circuit

Tags: ltspice

I have simulated two circuits, one is an RC filter and other is a Capacitance multiplier.

**My aim of experiment is to validate a decrease in Iout (load current) of CM circuit as compared to load current in RC filter circuit.**

Theoretically,

**Iout (CM circuit) < Iout (RC filter)**

**Vp-p (CM circuit) < Vp-p (RC filter)**

**My results:**

**1.RC filter**

Vout (dc) = 0.0458716 ( .op 300ms)

**Iout (dc) = 0.00458716**

Vout (ac) = 43.7 ~ 48 mV  (.tran 300ms)

**Iout (ac) = 4.80 ~ 4.37 mA**

**Vp-p (ripple) = 0.00437018  (.meas)**

**2.CM circuit**

Vout (dc) = 0.323751

**Iout (dc) = 0.0323751**

Vout (ac) = 322 ~ 327 mV

**Iout (ac) = 32.65 ~ 32.15 ma**

**Vp-p (ripple) = 0.00521016 (.meas)**

From the above results its quite clear that implementing CM circuit causes Iout to increase which particularly **against** the aim of the CM circuit. As the CM circuit works by decreasing the load current which according to load POV can be visualised as increase in capacitance.

We can also see the peak to peak ripple voltage in both the circuits, Vp-p for CM circuit should be less than Vp-p ripple of an RC filter, but again the simulations results are quite opposite.

Whats wrong here??

Link to LTspice files -https://filebin.net/d1d2wnjhi6wskl3n

[image]

[image]

Comment: Top cct is a current amplifier but emitter follows base voltage with a diode drop but similar AC voltage, Bottom is an attenuator for both AC and DC

Comment: Your load is too low for the RC case, while for the CM, the transistor can deliver the current if correctly polarized.

Comment: The schizophrenic text sizes in your screenshots are giving me cancer.